# If current date is selected I need this function to run on another field

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, timepicker

I am using this [datepicker](https://github.com/joshsalverda/datepickr) and this [timepicker](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#timepicker-plugin-for-jquery). I want to develop JS code that will determine if the user has selected the current date on the datepicker, if so this will trigger a function for the timepicker that will disable all the times previous to the actual time. I am new to JavaScript, so I have only gotten so far.

HTML:

```
<input id="datemax" placeholder="Enter the date of incident" type="text"/>

<input id="timemax" placeholder="Enter the time of incident" type="text"/>
```

I have written the code for disabling past times before the actual time here, which works but will stay constant no matter what date is chosen:

```
function getCurrentTime(date) {
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';

  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; 
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;

  return hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
}
var timesAvailable = {
        'timeFormat': 'h:i A',
        'disableTimeRanges': [['12am', getCurrentTime(new Date())]]
    };
$('#timemax').timepicker(timesAvailable);
```

I am wondering what would be required to implement the said JS function into my form. I presume a second function would need to be developed and will need to use `var datemax = document.getElementById("datemax").value;` to call the value from the date field.

I have developed a bit of incomplete pseudocode code here:

```
    function datetimeSelect{

    var currentDate = new Date()

    var datemax = document.getElementById("datemax").value;

    if (datemax = currentDate){ 

    //activate 

    "function(getCurrentTime(date))" //Can't select any time before now, greyed out
    return false;
    }
    else (datemax does not equal to currentDate)
    {
    any time can be selected
    return true;
    {
```

So for example if a date that is not today is selected, the timepicker will return to it's default functionality without any greyed out times.

Comment: I guess i saw this type of question yesterday too

Comment: I haven't found a resolution yet, apologies for the posts.

Comment: That's okay . I saw that plugin problem is that it doesn't have any event like `beforeShow` or like that so no way you can modify the behavior just before its been shown .So either you can use something like jquery UI or initialize plugin with latest limit and show.Still let me see